# How to create a table in a MS access database in C#

Tags: c#

I need to create a table in MS access database.
Consider, 'ConfigStructure.mdb' being my database name and i need to create a table in this database in C#.

How can i do this? I tried with the below code but its not working.

```
        OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + frmMain.strFilePath + "\\ConfigStructure.mdb");
        myConnection.Open();
        string strTemp = " KEY Text, VALUE Text ";
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
        myCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE table1(" + strTemp + ")";
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myCommand.Connection.Close();
```

This is the error that i get,

```
"System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in field definition
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)\r\n   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)\r\n   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)\r\n   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)"
```

Comment: Could you add any errors or warnings you get when you try to run this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Replace

```
string strTemp = " KEY Text, VALUE Text ";
```

with

```
string strTemp = " [KEY] Text, [VALUE] Text ";
```

I think the reason for this is that 'KEY' an 'VALUE' are reserved keywords in Access or SQL.

Answer (score 2):

KEY and VALUE are both [reserved words](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335). Particularly it is probably getting hung up on "KEY" because you can specify `PRIMARY KEY` as a constraint in a `CREATE TABLE` command.

Try using different column names or surrounding them by brackets (e.g. [KEY]) if you *really* want to use them (not suggested).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is using the word KEY as a column name - this is probably a reserved word. Try using different column names.

Answer (score 1):

"KEY" and "VALUE" are reserved words in MS Access. If you wish to use those names for your fields you will need to enclose them in square brackets:

```
string strTemp = " [KEY] Text, [VALUE] Text ";
```

Answer (score 0):

On my computer, Windows 7 sp1 Professional 64-bit, I found Microsoft ADO Ext. 2.8 for DDL and Security in *C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado\msadox28.dll*.

It is also found as a reference:

[image]

which is included as **ADOX** in the references

[image]

By default, columns are created as **text[255]**.  Here are a few examples to create columns as different datatypes.

```
table.Columns.Append("PartNumber", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 6); // text[6]
table.Columns.Append("AnInteger", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger); // Integer
```

I found this list of datatypes to create and read access database fields

> Access Text = adVarWChar
>
> Access Memo = adLongVarWChar
>
> Access Numeric Byte = adUnsignedTinyInt
>
> Access Numeric Integer = adSmallInt
>
> Access Numeric Long Integer = adInteger
>
> Access Numeric Single Precision = adSingle
>
> Access Numeric Double Precision = adDouble
>
> Access Numeric Replicatie-id = adGuid
>
> Access Numeric Decimal = adNumeric
>
> Access Date / Time = adDate
>
> Access Currency = adCurrency
>
> Access AutoNumber = adInteger
>
> Access Yes / No = adBoolean
>
> Access HyperLink = adLongVarWChar

Answer (score 0):

You should always write names of the tables and columns in these []
Your example:

```
OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + frmMain.strFilePath + "\\ConfigStructure.mdb");
myConnection.Open();
string strTemp = " [KEY] Text, [VALUE] Text ";
OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
myCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [table1](" + strTemp + ")";
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
myCommand.Connection.Close();
```

Works perfect.